# ServiceBus Deadletter queue cleanup using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

We want to clean up ServiceBus DeadLetter Queue periodically using Azure Logic Apps. The idea is to loop over all DeadLetter messages once a day and delete messages older than x days.

I implemented periodic "Recurrence" task with "Get messages from a queue (peek lock)". When they meet my condition they are completed and therefore removed from queue. This works with a few hundreds of messages. But when I tested this with thousands of messages it started to return messages already visited during current run. I included a condition that terminates processing if the same messageId is processed again.

Is there a way to achieve what we want? So to loop over all messages removing some and preserving others without visiting any of them repeatedly?

Here is the simplified scheme of the flow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to skip Logic Apps altogether. We ended up creating secondary queue with lifetime set to desired value (for how long we want to archive DL messages). We turned off sending of expired messages to the DL of this secondary queue. Then we set forwarding of DL messages into this secondary queue. This way no more processing is needed nor any logic triggered periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your For Each needs Concurrency Control. The Get Messages action will return X messages (20 by default) from the queue, then the For Each action runs in parallel and those actions (inside the For Each) are not waiting for all of them to complete before it exits that loop and go around again with the Do Until. I would test changing the For Each Settings/Concurrency Control (ellipsis on right side) and lower the Degree of Parallelism to a low number.

Comment: A tried to set "Get messages from a queue" parallelism to 1. That resulted in foreach loops having only 1 iteration. Until has no parallelism setting, therefore we can leave that out. The result was the same - after 35s the same message was received again. 
There could be something going on with lock duration (30s in my case) after which message previously peeked is received again. But I have no clue as to what to do about it even if it is related to lock.